# SendGrid unable to send email, firebase functions. (code: 403)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am using `Firebase Functions` to host the `SendGrid` implementation and I am not able to send emails with the emails that are not in the "Single Sender Verification" list in `SendGrid` .

I am getting the following error when trying to send email from `randomemail@gmail.com`:

> at node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:146:29
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) code: 403

I am able to send the emails from the emails that I added to the [Single Sender Verification list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWcAJ.png) in the `SendGrid`.

Here is my firebase function implementation, please help. I think the problem is related to domain cross origin or something with `SandGrid`.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

exports.emailMessage = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    sgMail.setApiKey("my key is here");

   const msg = {
    to: 'stanmozolevskiy@gmail.com', //here is one of the emails that I added to the Singlie Sender verification
    from: data.sender, // only works with email from 
    subject: `${data.name} sent you email`,
    text: data.message,
    html: `<strong>${data.message}</strong>`,
  }
  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Email sent');
    })
    .catch((error:any) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
    return{"status": "sucess", data: data};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendgrid allows only emails sent from a a verified email, but you can use the  `replyTo` property in order to solve the problem.

```
const msg = {
    to: verifiedEmail,
    from: verifiedEmail,
    **replyTo: data.sender,** 
    subject: `${data.name} sent you email`,
    text: data.message,
    html: `<strong>${data.message}</strong>`,
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting (the following) error when trying to send email from
> randomemail@gmail.com:
>
> ...
>
> I am able to send the emails from the emails that I added to the
> Single Sender Verification list in the SendGrid.

This is normal, Sendgrid allows only emails sent from a a verified email, in order to avoid potential malicious users sending emails in the name (i.e. "in the mail") of someone else.

---

Note that if your sender addresses are coming from the same email domain you can do a [Domain Authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) and avoid registering each email address of the domain.

Comment: Thank you for your response Renaud, I don't think it is the case. Even if I use somebody's email that I know it is legit is still gives me the same error. So if the client wants to send me an email, I need to add them into the Single Sender Verification list in the SendGrid? (does not sound right)

Comment: "Even if I use somebody's email that I know it is legit". I'll be a bit "direct" => What's important for Sendgrid is that THEY know that the email is legit not that you know it. They cannot trust the users of their services, so they need to verify that a user is the owner of all the senders addresses he/she uses with their service.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not the case because when I follow this tutorial https://www.edwardbeazer.com/sending-email-with-firebase-functions-and-sendgrid/ I am able to set that up correctly. But the tutorial example does not allow me to pass parameters so I had to modify it to what I have now.

Comment: You may be interested by https://sendgrid.com/blog/dont-send-email-from-domains-you-dont-control/ and https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification. Note that **If you have an [authenticated domain](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) and your sender email address matches that domain exactly, your sender identity will be verified automatically**.

Comment: Twilio SendGrid evangelist here. Renaud is correct, you can't just send from any address when using SendGrid. You can either go through [domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) or [verify a single email address](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification), though domain authentication is preferred for production uses.